# Error about Google Drive in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, google-drive-api

I try to learn how to do Google Drive application.I looked in this site (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs). When I add reference for google drive,I used Manage Nuget Packages.I searched Google.Apis and installed it.When I clean and build solution,there are some errors.These are

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenAuth' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'OAuth2' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Google.Apis.Authentication' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'OAuth2' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Google.Apis.Authentication' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error 4   The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Google.Apis' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 5   The type or namespace name 'IAuthorizationState' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Error 6   The type or namespace name 'NativeApplicationClient' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar build error when following the https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs
example in a MVC project. This example builds and executes fine in a Console application.

Found a different code example for OAuth 2.0 in a MVC application (section: Web applications (ASP.NET MVC))
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

or also
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Drive.Sample/?repo=samples

Answer (score 0):

DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2 I find by nuget